# How i add PHP or JavaScript code to choose new URL from drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wrote this code for two pages

1st page is index.php, and 2nd is load.php .
  The main function of index.php to load 2nd page load.php and update  data each 4 sec come from $url.

The two pages work fine and now i need to add additional code using (drop-down menu )to allow choose different url buy change variable $url .
I tired to add submit form, but the $url variable not carry out the value.
Any help about adding this code?

index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $("#screen").load('load.php')
}, 4000);});</script><div id="screen"></div>
```

and page load.php

```
   <html>
    <style>

    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
        tr:nth-child(even){
            background-color: #dddddd
        }
    </style>
<body>
<?php
$url="https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/bchusd";
$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc,TRUE);
$bid=$json["bid"];
$ask=$json["ask"];
echo '<table>
       <tr><th>Company</th><th>Bid</th><th>Ask</th></tr>
       <tr><td>Bitstamp(USD)</td><td>'.$bid.'</td><td>'.$ask.'</td></tr>     
    </table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change $.load to $.post or $.ajax and pass the url as a parameter for load.php to collect eg $_POST['url']

after the change you will need to do a bit more lifting on in the javascript callback to add the new html to the #screen element eg $('#screen').html(repsonse.html);

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/